Given a datetime string and a time zone identifier, how can I get the corresponding UTC datetime, server-side?
I'm in a situation where, on the server, I have two values:

a datetime string like "2020-01-01T00:00:00"
a timezone string like "America/Chicago"

How can I create a UTC Date corresponding to this moment in time?

More details..
In my web application, I'm designing a schedule that looks like this

The user can select a startDate and an endDate to run a query to fetch all the events in that range. In turn, this simply updates the URL to something like
www.foo.com/user/123/schedule?startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-01-05

In this example, the user is requesting all events between 2020-01-01 00:00:00 and 2020-01-05 11:59:59 in their local time zone.
From the client, I could convert these local timestamps to UTC timestamps and then make the request, like this
www.foo.com/user/123/schedule?startDate=2020-01-01T06:00:00Z&endDate=2020-01-06T05:59:59Z

BUT

I think the previous URL format is prettier and easier to understand for the user
If someone navigates directly to www.foo.com/user/123/schedule, I want the ability to check their cookies for a timeZone string and choose reasonable defaults for startDate and endDate.


? regardless of their geographical location, all servers are in UTC Zero...

@MisterJojo I understand. I guess you're confused by my question.. Let me put it like this.. "How do I convert "2020-01-01T00:00:00 CT" to it corresponding "UTC" timestamp? ("CT" = "Central Time" = "America/Chicago")

@Yogi, the date is not stored in a database. It comes from a request from the user/client. The request is formatted like /fooEndPoint?startDate=2020-01-01 and a cookie contains their timezone string.

@Yogi link above is the correct way. You can't do this directly with JavaScript because it doesn't have zoneinfo information. Also note: in your question, you (correctly) used a timezone id, a.k.a. "IANA Time Zone Names". The offset designators like "CT" are meaningless except as a "friendly" format to display to users. These cannot be used to determine a specific point in time because they are not unique. There are over 60 different timezones that do or have previously used "CST".

@Yogi please see the update to my post. Thanks!

your interface is weird. how do you manage a request for information between 2am and 3am on the 2nd Sunday of March, knowing that this time slot does not exist (DST time change)? (and conversely for the switch to STD time, to distinguish the one between 2am and 1am from the next one between 1am and 2am?)

@MisterJojo users of my application get to choose a date range, not a timestamp range. If you use Google calendar, play around with the "week" view and imagine how it might work if it let you pick a range of dates.

Since you're only allowing users to select a date, you shouldn't append the T00:00:00. The ISO format allows for a "local date" type like 2024-11-22, which does not represent a specific point in time without timezone info, or date-time representations, which should include the offset information to identify a specific moment.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
You can't do this with plain JavaScript because the standard date library doesn't include zoneinfo (the temporal api will provide this someday...) This will do what you want:
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'

// combining a local date and a zone can identify a specific point in time
// then we convert to UTC
const toUtc = (localDate: string, zone: string) => {
  return DateTime.fromISO(localDate, { zone }).toUTC().toJSDate()
}

const utcDate = toUtc('2020-01-01', 'America/Chicago')

// outputs 2020-01-01T06:00:00.000Z
console.log(utcDate.toISOString())

Also note (repeating a bit from my comment above): in your question, you (correctly) used a timezone id, a.k.a. "IANA Time Zone Names". The offset designators like "CT" are meaningless except as a "friendly" format to display to users. These cannot be used to determine a specific point in time because they are not unique. There are over 60 different timezones that do or have previously used "CST".
